# Grails spring security oauth2 provider request for resource with correct bearer token redirects to login

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

As the title implies, I have a controller method protected by the oAuth2 plugin, but when I send a request to it including a correct Authorization: Bearer <token> (using Postman), the response I get is the HTML for the login page.

Method in question:

```
@Secured(["ROLE_USER", "#oauth2.clientHasAnyRole('ROLE_CLIENT', 'ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')"])
    def getUserData(){
        response.setContentType("application/json")
        User u = springSecurityService.currentUser
        println u
        render u.mseUserInfo
    }
```

Config.groovy:

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl = '/mse/login'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'cz.improvisio.MSEauthProvider.user.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'cz.improvisio.MSEauthProvider.user.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'cz.improvisio.MSEauthProvider.user.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/oauth/authorize.dispatch':[
        "ROLE_USER",
        "isFullyAuthenticated()"
    ],
    '/oauth/token.dispatch':[
        "ROLE_USER",
        "isFullyAuthenticated()"
    ],
    '/mse/login':["permitAll"],
    '/mse/':["permitAll"],
    '/**':["permitAll"]]



// Added by the Spring Security OAuth2 Provider plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.clientLookup.className = 'cz.improvisio.MSEauthProvider.user.Client'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.authorizationCodeLookup.className = 'cz.improvisio.MSEauthProvider.user.AuthCode'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.accessTokenLookup.className = 'cz.improvisio.MSEauthProvider.user.AccessToken'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.refreshTokenLookup.className = 'cz.improvisio.MSEauthProvider.user.RefreshToken'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/oauth/token': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-oauth2ProviderFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter',
    '/securedOAuth2Resources/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,-oauth2BasicAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter',
    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-statelessSecurityContextPersistenceFilter,-oauth2ProviderFilter,-clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter,-oauth2BasicAuthenticationFilter,-oauth2ExceptionTranslationFilter'
]
```

This is the client creation from Bootstrap.groovy:

```
new Client(
                clientId: 'testClient',
                authorizedGrantTypes: [
                    'authorization_code',
                    'refresh_token',
                    'implicit',
                    'password',
                    'client_credentials'
                ],
                authorities: ['ROLE_CLIENT'],
                scopes: ['read', 'write'],
                redirectUris: ['http://test.com']).save(flush: true)
```

And one more slightly related question: I couldnt find a way to get the User to whose resources the access token should be linked to, so I assumed Id be able to get it through springSecurityService. Is this the correct way of doing so? Or do I need to pass the userId to the method (and will OpenAM do it?)?

Comment: Can you post the roles available to your client which you are using to authenticate?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal added bit of code from Bootstrap where client is created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I didnt have the proper filter chain set up for my action. Changing config to

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/oauth/token': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-oauth2ProviderFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter',
    '/securedOAuth2Resources/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,-oauth2BasicAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter',
'/myController/getUserData': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,-oauth2BasicAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter',
    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-statelessSecurityContextPersistenceFilter,-oauth2ProviderFilter,-clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter,-oauth2BasicAuthenticationFilter,-oauth2ExceptionTranslationFilter'
]
```

fixed it.

Comment: what confused me is "securedOAuth2Resources" i was thinking it's one of the spring's stuff instead of mine.

Comment: @Вадим in fact "securedOAuth2Resources" is a class (Controller) they show in their documentation and you can see here: http://bluesliverx.github.io/grails-spring-security-oauth2-provider/v3/manual/guide/gettingStarted.html#resourceAccess